How to debug the ODBC driver manager error 'not found and no default driver specified' on IISNode?
I cannot get a project to start for local development because I keep getting the error:
Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
The problem seems to happen only on IIS - run the script that connects to the database from the shell works.
I am using Windows 11 Virtual Machine with Parallels on M3 Mac. My database is in a docker container on Linux Ubuntu x86_64 emulation. I am using the msnodesqlv8 module for the connection.
I can connect SQL Server Management Studio, ODBC Data Source returns successful test of connection.
It is only IIS that is tripping me. (I think)
